# How to load DLL from `lib` subdirectory of JAR file?

Tags: java, gradle, java-native-interface, native

I have included (with Gradle) some JAR with native libraries (DLL), which are packed with `lib` subdirectory above the DLL files:

[image]

Unfortunately,

```
System.loadLibrary('JCudaRuntime-0.9.2-windows-x86_64');
```

causes

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JCudaRuntime-0.9.2-windows-x86_64 in java.library.path
```

How to fix this?

Is it possible to specify sub-directory for `loadLibrary`? Where should native libraries should better located? Just in the root of JAR files?

Can I teach Gradle to look for natives under `lib` inside JARs?

Answer (score 1):

the `libs` directory ordinary is for `jar` and `aar` libraries.

`x86_64` assembly would go to `src/main/jniLibs/x86_64`

```
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("JCudaDriver-0.9.2-windows-x86_64");
        System.loadLibrary("JCudaRuntime-0.9.2-windows-x86_64");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

one can/could also change the path:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDir "src/main/jniLibs"
        jni.srcDirs = "src/main/cpp"
    }
}
```

the issue with that just is, that the `x86_64` platform-specific sub-directory would still be expected. extracting `.dll` from the `.jar` and dropping them into a project's `jniLibs` directory might be the most simple - because while they're inside a `jar` with a `lib` directory, they might not be found where expected; which is unnecessarily complicating things.